# Parse many XML files in batches with PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, xml, laravel, mariadb

I have my code already working, it will parse the files and insert the records, the issue that is stumping me as I have never had to do this is, how can I tell my code to parse 1-300 files then wait then parse the next "batch" 301-500 and so on until it's finished parsing all the files. I'm needed to parse over 50 thousand files, so obviously I'm reaching php's memory limit and execution time which has already been increased but I don't think I could set it extremely high to process 50 thousand.

I need help with how do I tell my code to run 1-x then rerun and run x-y?

My code is (Note, I am gathering more information that what's in my snip below)

```
$xml_files = glob(storage_path('path/to/*.xml'));

foreach ($xml_files as $file) {

$data = simplexml_load_file($file);

... Parse XML and get certain nodes ...
$name = $data->record->memberRole->member->name;

... SQL to insert record into DB ...
Members::firstOrCreate(
    ['name' =>  $name]
);

}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues and share your solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest, if inelegant solution, is calling the script multiple times with an offset and using a for loop instead of forach.

```
$xml_files = glob(storage_path('path/to/*.xml'));
$offset = $_GET['offset'];
// Or if calling the script via command line:
// $offset = $argv[1];
$limit = $offset + 300;

for ($i = $offset; $i < $limit; $i++) {
    $data = simplexml_load_file($xml_files[$i]);
    // process and whatever
}
```

If you're calling the script as a web page, just add a query param like `my-xml-parser.php?offset=300` and get offset like this: `$offset = $_GET['offset']`.

If you're calling this as a command line script, call it like this: `php my-xml-parser.php 300`, and get the offset from argv: `$offset = $argv[1]`

EDIT
If it's a web script, you can try and add a curl call that would call itself with the next offset without waiting for an answer.